# Prevent useEffect hook with two dependencies from running twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to use two properties of a state in the same `useEffect` hook:

`state.keyEvent`: `keydown` from `document` (to listen to commands like `Ctrl + R`).

`state.value`: value of `input` (to perform a text search).

```
import { useEffect, useReducer } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const initialState = { keyEvent: {}, value: "builder" };
  const [state, updateState] = useReducer(
    (state: any, updates: any) => ({ ...state, ...updates }),
    initialState
  );

  function handleInputChange(event: any) {
    updateState({ value: event.target.value });
  }

  function handleDocumentKeyDown(event: any) {
    updateState({ keyEvent: event });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", handleDocumentKeyDown);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleDocumentKeyDown);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("keyEvent:", state);
  }, [state]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        id="input"
        type="text"
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        value={state.value}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This works—except the `useEffect` hook runs twice when I type in the `input` element.

I think I have to tell the code: If `state.value` updates, ignore `state.keyEvent` and don't run the hook again.

Is that correct? If so, how to accomplish this?

[image: Edit useState same value rerender (forked)]

Note: if I put `state.keyEvent` and `state.useEffect` in different `useEffect` hooks, I won't be able to have the latest value of `state.value` in the hook containing `state.keyEvent` (because the hook containing `state.keyEvent` will run first than the hook containing `state.value`).

Comment: it runs twice because you run `handleInputChange`, `handleDocumentKeyDown`. What is your goal?

Comment: I don't get it why do you have two variables in one state

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava I want to tell the hook that has `[state]` as dependency this: If `state.value` updates, ignore `state.keyEvent` and don't run the hook again.

Comment: @Konrad I need two variables in one hook: one to store to key presses (including outside of the input). Another to store the value of an input.

Comment: I'm curious what is the use-case of that?

Comment: @alexchenco it seems XY problem: https://xyproblem.info/. I would advise to also add to your question what functionality you want to achieve.

Comment: A faq here may be how to handle the "enter" key. If it is about enter (or some other special key like this) then this is a duplicate.

Comment: @Konrad @Konrad When the user presses, for example, `Ctrl + ]` I want to trigger an action. If the user types in the `input` element, I want to search for text that matches the `value`. It tried doing each in different hooks ... but the `value` of `input` always came with a delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to just listen for commands like ctrl+r, you can pre-filter them in your keyboard handler and exclude from being pushed to the input:

```js
  ....

  function isCommand(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    return event.ctrlKey && event.key === 'r';
  }

  function handleDocumentKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (isCommand(event)) {
      event.preventDefault();
      updateState({ keyEvent: event });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Wow, such a simple solution. I can't believe it works. One question: why did you add `event.preventDefault();`? The implementation seems to work fine without it: https://codesandbox.io/s/usestate-same-value-rerender-forked-twtlux?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: It's just in case you want to capture keys that might result in the input changed eventually (if you want to prevent that for whatever reason, like drop ctrl+v key for example.) if you don't need to process keys like ctrl+v in a special way, then there is no need to prevent default.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the solution. It simple and smart. I was stuck with this problem for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

`keydown` event always fires first, so it's enough to check for it

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("keyEvent:", state);
}, [state.keyEvent]);
```

Comment: It won't fire if the input is changed otherwise (like, copy-paste from a context menu using a mouse *only*)

Comment: Ah, so simple. I wonder if I'll have the latest value of `state.value` inside that hook. I'll check when I arrive home.

Comment: @alexchenco it won't sadly

Comment: @alexchenco when you press key inside input now, first `handleDocumentKeyDown` fires, which updates state, then useEffect is called, then `handleInputChange` is called, which updates state and again useEffect is called. Clearly first useEffect doesn't see value from `handleInputChange`